# Trouble with AJAX inserting data in DB

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX to build a chat system for a twitch video. The point is to dynamically display the submitted messages without the page being reloaded, and it works. However the messages aren't submitted to my Database and upon page refresh the submitted messages are gone. The ones that i manually inserted in the DB are displayed. Here's my code :

Dashboard.twig :

```
<script>

$("#forminput").submit(function(e){
    var url = "dashboard";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#forminput").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json', //what is returned
        success : function(data)
        {
            $("#table").append("<tr><td>" + data.name + "</td><td>" + data.comment + "</td></tr>");
        }

    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

DisplayCommentsModel:-

```
private $name;
private $comment;

public function printComments()
{
    $app = \Yee\Yee::getInstance();

    $cols = Array ("name", "comment");

    $comments = $app->db['db1']->get("comments", null, $cols);  
    if ($app->db['db1']->count > 0)
    {
        return $comments;
    }
}
```

AddCommentsModel

```
private $name;
private $comment;

public function __construct($name, $comment)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->comment = $comment;
}

public function comment()
{
    if ($this->validateEmptyFields() == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ($this->validateFilledFields() == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public function validateEmptyFields()
{
    if(empty($this->name) || empty($this->comment))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}

public function validateFilledFields()
{
    $nameLenght = strlen($this->name);
    $commentLenght = strlen($this->comment);

    if($nameLenght < 2 && $commentLenght < 2)
    {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}

public function insertCommentsInDb()
{
    $app = \Yee\Yee::getInstance();

    $data = array(
        "name" => $this->name,
        "comment" => $this->comment
        );

    $app->db['db1']->insert('comments', $data);
}
```

CommentsController :

```
public function index()
{
    $app = $this->getYee();
    $newDisplayCommentsModel = new DisplayCommentsModel();
    $comments = $newDisplayCommentsModel->printComments();
    $data = array(
        'comments' => $comments
    );
    $app->render('dashboard/dashboard.twig', $data);
}

/**
 * @Route('/dashboard')
 * @Name('dashboard.post')
 * @Method('POST')
 */
public function post()
{
    $app = $this->getYee();

    $name = $app->request->post('name');
    $comment = $app->request->post('comment');

    //add to database

    $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'comment' => $comment
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: How you are getting `$("#forminput").serialize()` values in `php`

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What do you mean by getting the values in php ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz just understood what you mean. Its thanks to my Comments controller

Comment: Sure you've the right values in your variables? Try to display `$data` array somewhere before you insert it, just to be sure the values are in the array.

Comment: Added my ComentsController, its has what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In post function in your CommentsController file, you are not inserting data into database. The code section below will just echo back whatever is received.

```
$data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'comment' => $comment
    );
echo json_encode($data);
```

You should call insertCommentsInDb() available in AddCommentsModel  before you send back the data

Answer (score 1):

$data=json_encode($data); // not need echo

$this->db->insert('tableName',$data);
// You forgot this line and this will insert json_format to database

Comment: Where do you suggest i put the "$this->db->insert('tableName',$data); " ? Doesn't work in the post() function.